# Can you create a user in auth.users from email address input, inside of an RPC function? (Supabase)

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, authentication, supabase

I have an RPC function in Supabase, which attempts to return the uuid from a public.profiles table for a given email address.  It returns the uuid if there is a matching unique email in public.profiles.

If it fails to find a matching email in public.profiles, it should create a new user in auth.users based on that given email address.  Here is the code I am currently using in the RPC function:

```sql
DECLARE
  profile_uuid UUID;
BEGIN
  -- Check if email exists in public.profiles
  SELECT id INTO profile_uuid FROM public.profiles WHERE public.profiles.email = $1;
  
  -- If email does not exist in public.profiles, create a new user in auth.users
  IF profile_uuid IS NULL THEN

INSERT INTO
  auth.users (
    id,
    instance_id,
    ROLE,
    aud,
    email,
    raw_app_meta_data,
    raw_user_meta_data,
    is_super_admin,
    encrypted_password,
    created_at,
    updated_at,
    last_sign_in_at,
    email_confirmed_at,
    confirmation_sent_at,
    confirmation_token,
    recovery_token,
    email_change_token_new,
    email_change
  )
VALUES
  (
    gen_random_uuid(),
    '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
    'authenticated',
    'authenticated',
    $1,
    '{"provider":"email","providers":["email"]}',
    '{}',
    FALSE,
    crypt('Pa55word!', gen_salt('bf')),
    NOW(),
    NOW(),
    NOW(),
    NOW(),
    NOW(),
    '',
    '',
    '',
    ''
  )
  RETURNING id INTO profile_uuid;
    -- INSERT INTO auth.users (email) VALUES ($1) RETURNING id INTO profile_uuid;

  END IF;
  
  RETURN profile_uuid;
END;
```

When I try calling this function using a Supabase client in a Netlify function, I get this response:

```
{
  code: '42883',
  details: null,
  hint: 'No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.',
  message: 'function encode(text, unknown) does not exist'
}
```

Is it possible to create a new entry in auth.users as described above?  If so, could somebody help me fix my code to do this?

Comment: The source of the error was calling `encode` in another related function to this one.  Removing `encode` from the other function solved the problem and got this working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The source of the error was calling `encode` in another related function to this one. Removing an `encode` call from the other function solved the problem and got this working as expected.

The rest of the code works as expected for creating a new user in auth.users inside an RPC function, based on a solution [from this discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/orgs/supabase/discussions/5248#discussioncomment-3200322)